# Exception " There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread' " while running over new loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-asyncio, event-loop

The is the simple test code and the result.

```
import asyncio

async def test():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    asyncio.set_event_loop(None)      # Clear the main loop.
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()   # Create a new loop.
    loop.run_until_complete(test())   # Run coroutine over the new loop
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(test())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 387, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "test_test.py", line 5, in test
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 510, in sleep
    loop = events.get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py", line 632, in get_event_loop
    return get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py", line 578, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.
```

I run the `async def test()` over the `new loop` and expected that `asyncio.sleep(1)` which is nested by `test()` also use the `new loop`.

In contrast to that, `sleep()` still seems to access `main loop` I set as `None`.

I know I can re-set a `main loop` as the `new loop` with `asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)` before calling `run_until_complete()` and it will work with no exception.

However, I want to know it is normal for `asyncio` that `main loop` Must be set and is used for coroutines regardless of a loop over which coroutine is run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to know it is normal for `asyncio` that main loop Must be set and is used for coroutines regardless of a loop over which coroutine is run.

This used to be required prior to Python 3.6. The reason is that functions like `asyncio.sleep()` need an event loop to be able to use `loop.call_later()` to schedule a wake-up call to complete the future.

As of Python 3.6 (or 3.5.3, which included a fix for [the issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue28613)), when `get_event_loop()` is invoked from a coroutine driven by an event loop, it always returns the event loop that drives it. As a result, your code works correctly.

The new behavior is not mentioned in the online documentation, but is in [the docstring](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6fcb6cfb139ade1aac6dbee0b18ca72b18cbe0d2/Lib/asyncio/events.py#L735):

> When called from a coroutine or a callback (e.g. scheduled with `call_soon` or similar API), this function will always return the running event loop.

Comment: Please replace 3.7 with 3.5.3

Comment: @Andrew Svetlov, it seems to work with `python 3.5.3` but where can I find the fixed content on this issue?  I couldn't find any mention about this on [release note](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-353/)

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov Replacing 3.7 with 3.5.3 wouldn't explain why the snippet fails on 3.6. Python 3.7 was the first version to document the new behavior of `get_event_loop()`, and I've seen it mentioned in various places as a 3.7 innovation. It might be interesting to find out why the OP's code works in 3.5.3, but that doesn't change the answer to the OP's more generic question of whether it is required to set an event loop to use asyncio.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov I now see that the change was treated [as a bugfix](https://bugs.python.org/issue28613) and backported to bugfix branches. I've now updated the answer to link to the concrete issue. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Actually the feature was introduced in Python 3.6 and backported to 3.5.3. The snippet uses 3.5, I guess 3.5.2.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov You're right. The remaining question of why it failed for me in 3.6 is explained by the fact that my Ubuntu 16.10 comes with the 3.6.0b2 pre-release.

Comment: @SangminKim The change is in the [full 3.5 change log](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-5-3-release-candidate-1), look for `bpo-28613`.

Comment: The [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#event-loop-policy-interface) link is dead. Is this the correct refertence? [new in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio-event-loop)

Comment: @JosiahL. The quoted text appears to have been lost in the recent overhaul of the documentation. What's bad is that I can't find the equivalent statement (that documents that `get_event_loop` works like `get_running_loop` if the loop is actually running) in the new text.